# In teams custom apps, hide/show static tabs options

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am creating a custom app which will be rendering the content from the url.
But I need to show some tabs for only some users. and this will be decided at run time.

How can I achieve this feature in teams custom app.

Comment: This is something which is not possible as of now. This is by Design, We can not hide/show personal tabs on demand

Comment: Ok, @Trinetra-MSFT.
But can you suggest me any alternative for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an option in Teams today.

if you want / need to build this today,(and do not need a bot in the personal scope)
then I suggest the following pattern :

- Add a **single** personal/static tab
- Add authentication, preferably [Tab SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso)
- Run the tab in full screen, this will hide any other tabs and the chat
  note: currently only available for LoB/tenant apps using [manifest 1.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema?view=msteams-client-js-latest#isfullscreen) or newer
- then in your code show/hide the content and navigation using authentication & authorization. you can to show / hide your own (sub)tabs